# How to handle number_format output in php?

Tags: php

I am getting the following output correctly:

```
<?php echo number_format("12312.312","1"); // Correct Output 12312.3 ?>
```

but in the following case

```
<?php echo number_format("12312","1"); // Getting output 12312.0 but requires only 12312 ?>
```

So basically, I want to control my output i.e. it should add decimal place only if my decimal digit is greater than 0.

Comment: You are specifying that there should be 1 decimal place.  So number_format is giving you one decimal place.  What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
<?php
$number = 12312;
echo is_int($number) ? $number : number_format($number,"1");
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter for `number_format()` takes the number of decimals - so your example is the the expected result. Maybe you are intereseted in the [round()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) function which allows to round to a certain precision?

Comment: Yes I am aware of round() but problem is I am getting random number and I want to handle it accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean by "handle it accordingly?"  round($_, 1) will drop the decimal if it would be 0 by number_format.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the extra decimal place, use `<?php echo number_format(12312, 0);?>`

The "0" represents 0 decimal places

Answer (score 0):

simple casting it to float, usign (float), works.

e.g.

$num_1 = (float)1.0;

$num_2 = (float)1.1;

echo $num_1;
echo $num_2;

output:

1

1.1